# Gaussian Smoothing Window Size and Digital Image Processing

Tags: c, image, image-processing, gaussian, smoothing

Details on Gaussian Smoothing
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm

I have to implement a image smoother in a project I am working on and I have everything all worked out except window size. I am having a real issue with finding the proper window size. What is a general rule about it?

How do you pick a good window size for your gaussian smoothing algorithm to use?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. What is your motivation for applying a gaussian filter? Removing some kind of noise or artefact? To make some kind of visual effect? Something else?

Comment: To remove noise. But it is a pretty general requirement, I know.

Comment: OK - do you know anything about the noise ? If not then you may just need to let your user experiment with different kernel sizes.

Comment: I do not know anything about the noise.

Comment: OK - so let your user play with different kernel sizes so that they can find the best filter empirically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window size depends on the application but also on the standard deviation. For larger standard deviations you have to use larger windows. Otherwise, if you have a large standard deviation and a very small window size, than your filter becomes almost a mean filter. However, no need to have the window size larger than 6 times the standard deviation because furthermore the signal is almost 0.